# Enabling and disabling form fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with getting the JavaScript to do what I need it to.  I have a form with a country drop down list that has United States or Other; then I have a State field with a list of all 50 states in the US; then I have a text field for people to put what country they live in if they don't live in the United States.  What I want to be able to do is if United Sates is selected in the country drop down list I want the "other" text field to be disabled and the state drop down list enabled; then vice versa, if they select other, then the state drop down list is disabled and the "other" text field is enabled.  
Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="countryValidation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form2">
<form name="createForm" onsubmit="return createValidation();" method="get">
<p>Country:    <select id="country">
            <option value="0">United States</option>
            <option value="1">Other</option>
           </select>&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<p>State:    <select id="state">
          <option value="0">- -Select state- -</option>
          <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
          <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
          <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
          <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="California">California</option>
          <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
          <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
          <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
          <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
          <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
          <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
          <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
          <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
          <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
          <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
          <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
          <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
          <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
          <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
          <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
          <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="New York">New York</option>
          <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
          <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
          <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
          <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
          <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
          <option value="Virginia">virginia</option>
          <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
          <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
         </select>&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
 <p>Please type in what country you live in:
<input type="text" id="countryOther" />&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
```

And here is what I am trying to do with JavaScript:

```
function countryValidation ()
 {
  var country = document.forms["createForm"]["country"].value;
  var countryOther = document.forms["createForm"]["countryOther"];
  var state = document.forms["createForm"]["state"];

  if (country == 0)
   {
   countryOther.createAttribute("disabled","disabled");
   }
  else if (country == 1)
   {
   state.createAttribute("disabled","disabled");
   countryOther.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
 }
```

I do have another JavaScript function that Validates the whole form, because it is a form that I will be using to allow people to create an account.  I haven't gotten to the point of having an SQL server, nor have I learned SQL, PHP or ASP.net...  I am doing this for a project and could really use some help with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: If you pass *this* from the submit listener, you'll get a reference to the form and get it in the function like `function countryValidation(form){...}` and `document.forms["createForm"]["country"].value` can be `form.country.value`. Much less to type. :-)

Comment: For some reason when I have put it in as `form.country.value` it doesn't want to work so I put it in as `document.forms["createForm"]["country"].value` so that's why I've done it that way.

Comment: You need to pass *this* from the listener: `onsubmit="return createValidation(this);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you've asked.
I have also added in a focus command, as it makes for a smoother ui.
Once the user clicks Other, the focus goes automatically to the Other country textbox, letting them type.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhilleli/LsKDU/4/

```
function countryValidation()
 {
  var country = document.forms["createForm"]["country"].value;
  var countryOther = document.forms["createForm"]["countryOther"];
  var state = document.forms["createForm"]["state"];

  if (country == 0)
   {
   state.disabled=false;       //enable state
   state.focus();              //focus state 
   countryOther.value="";      //clear countryOther from any prev entry
   countryOther.disabled=true; //enable countryOther
   }
  else if (country == 1)
   {
   state.disabled=true;         //disable state
   state.value=0;               //clear state from any prev value
   countryOther.disabled=false; //enable countryOther
   countryOther.focus();        //focus on countryOther
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it works but only works if I make the change and then refresh the page.  I will figure out how to make the page refresh when input is made... or something like that.

Comment: So I think part of my problem is that I am having to check all of it on an out of date browser.  I'm pretty sure that the current browser installed on this computer is IE7, and there is no way I can update it do to the restrictions on this computer.  I will check it again when I get to my personal computer.  Thanks again Ben.  PS. Glad to know I was close

Comment: Please upvote if found helpful... that's how stack works

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote... I accepted the answer though.

Comment: `countryOther.value=""` would be better as `countryOther.selectedIndex = -1` so that no option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a slightly different approach? Something like this, perhaps ...

```
<form name="createForm" onsubmit="return createValidation();" method="get">
    <label for"country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country" onchange="countryValidation();">
        <option value="0">Select Country</option>
            <option value="1">United States</option>
            <option value="2">Other</option>
           </select>
    <div id="moreInfo"></div>
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function countryValidation() {
    var moreinfo = document.getElementById("moreInfo");
    var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
    if (country==1) {
        var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska"];
        var stateselect = '<select id="state" name="state">';
        for (var i=0; i<states.length; i++) {
            stateselect += '<option value="' + states[i] + '">' + states[i] + '</option>';
        }
        stateselect += '</select>';
        moreinfo.innerHTML = stateselect;
    } else if (country==2) {
        moreinfo.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="countryOther" name="countryOther" value="Please enter the name of your country" />';
    }
}
</script>
```